# What is difference between OUCH protocol and FIX protocol. Message for both protocol looks quite similar

Tags: fix-protocol

We are using fix earlier but client say implement OUCH for placing trade since that's faster . I checked on internet and message looks quite similar. How it get speed benefit. Please give me some example message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, FIX message is transferred in text format, while OUCH transfers messages in binary format, which leads to OUCH could transfer message in slim size and occupy less bandwidth over the network; for achieving higher performance over transmission.

Everything has a trade-off. Below has listed some comparing items between both for a reference.

**Data Format**
`FIX`: *Text*
`OUCH`: *Binary*

**Data Size**
`FIX`: *Big*
`OUCH`: *Slim*

**Data Length**
`FIX`: *Variable*
`OUCH`: *Fixed*

**Data Sequence**
`FIX`: *Explicit*
`OUCH`: *Implicit*

**Universality**
`FIX`: *Industrial standard; generally supported & accepted by most exchanges and clients*
`OUCH`: *Proprietary; limited to specific exchanges*

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that OUCH is a protocol that is specific to the NASDAQ stock exchanges. The FIX protocol is a standard that is supported by most exchanges.

The OUCH protocol is a faster protocol as it is designed as a low level native (binary) protocol, but as it is specific to NASDAQ exchanges you will have to have another module based on FIX to connect and trade on other exchanges.